# Write strings and float number to an ASCII file with python

Tags: python, list, numpy, arcgis, arcpy

I've been trying to concatenate two arrays (string array and float array) and then write the final array to a CSV file. However, I've been facing a lot of problems to solve it. I already tried a lot of tutorials in the internet about this topic, but no one worked properly for me.

The code that I`m writing use python to automate a serie of tasks in ArcGIS. After the code run and get all the mean values, I need to join the mean value from the raster file together with two strings.

I`ve already tried to join all the informations that I need in one single array, but I face problems when I try to save it to a CSV file.

The code is the following.

```
#Interpolation
        arcpy.gp.Idw_sa(out_Layer_shp, i_dia, arcpy.env.workspace + "\\Raster\\" + out_Layer_tif + ".tif", tamanho_celula, potencia_idw, "VARIABLE 12 12", "") 


        #Deleting the shape file
        arcpy.Delete_management(out_Layer_shp, "") 



        lista_final = np.array([], dtype = object)  #Final list
        contador = 0 #Counter 


        for mascara in bacias: #Importing shapefiles to clip the interpolated raster
            importar_camada = arcpy.env.workspace + "\\Shapefile\\Bacias\\" + mascara + ".shp"  
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(importar_camada, mascara)  



            #Variable to set the name of the layers that will be created and then clipped
            camada_para_recortar = out_Layer_tif + ".tif"
            camada_resultante = out_Layer + "_recortada"
            nome_do_raster = camada_resultante + "_" + mascara + ".tif" 

            #Code to interpolate
            arcpy.Clip_management(camada_para_recortar, "", arcpy.env.workspace  + "\\Raster\\Recortes\\" + camada_resultante + "_" + mascara + ".tif", mascara, "-3,402823e+038", "ClippingGeometry", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")

            #Getting the mean value from the raster clipped
            media = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management (nome_do_raster, "MEAN", "") 


            lista_strings = np.array([out_Layer, mascara]) #array string
            lista_medias = np.array([media]) #float string 

            arquivo_com_as_medias = "medias 01" #Name of the file to save the means values

            lista_numpy_temporaria = np.array([out_Layer, mascara, media], dtype = object) #Temporary list to save the data before
                                                                                                                        #it be added to the final array
            #lista_numpy_temporaria = lista_numpy_temporaria.reshape(1,3)

            lista_final = np.concatenate((lista_final, lista_numpy_temporaria)) #Concatenating the two arrays

            contador = contador + 1 #Incrementing the counter

        lista_final = lista_final.reshape(contador,3)    #reshape the final array   


        np.savetxt(arcpy.env.workspace  + "\\Dados\\Exportados\\" + arquivo_com_as_medias + ".csv", lista_final, fmt="%10s %10.3f", delimiter=";", header = "#1, #2")




        #Attempt to write the arrays based in a tutorial that I found, but it didn't work
        """         
        ab = np.zeros(lista_numpy_temporaria.size, dtype=[('var1', 'U6'), ('var2', float)])
        ab['var1'] = lista_strings
        ab['var2'] = lista_medias

        np.savetxt(arcpy.env.workspace  + "\\Dados\\Exportados\\" + arquivo_com_as_medias + ".csv", ab, fmt="%10s %10.3f")
        """


        print(lista_final)
```

The error message that I get from this code is the following

> Runtime error 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 50, in 
>     File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1031, in savetxt
>       raise error
>   ValueError: fmt has wrong number of % formats:  %10s %10.3f

The code have a lot of comments because of the many attempts that I've been making.

What I aiming to get is a CSV file with 3 columns and a lot of rows, the number of rows will vary depending the amount of data been interpolated. One example would be following:

```
RASTER FILE       SUB_BASIN       MEAN_VALUE 
out_Layer         mascara         99.99
```

Thank you.

**Edit 1**

The new message error after the solution suggested is the following:

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 210, in    File
>   "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line
>   1047, in savetxt
>       fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline)) TypeError: float argument required, not Result

The solution that I've found was to change the format from  fmt="%10s %10s %10.3f" to this

> `fmt="%10s %10s %10s"`

Although it is not the best solution, since it return numbers as strings.

The full code that I'm using is the following.

```
import arcpy
import numpy  as np

from arcpy import sa 
from arcpy.sa import *
from calendar import monthrange


# Set environment settings
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Projetos\\ArcGIS\\Teste9"  

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True 


#get the map document
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")


#get the data frame
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"la*")[0]





#Months and years to interpolate
mes = ["2"] #Months
ano = ["1994"] #Years

#Days to interpolate based in the month lenght
coluna_interpolada_28 = ["D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "D9", "D10", "D11", "D12", "D13", "D14", "D15", "D16", "D17", "D18", "D19", "D20", "D21", "D22", "D23", "D24", "D25", "D26", "D27", "D28"]  
coluna_interpolada_29 = ["D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "D9", "D10", "D11", "D12", "D13", "D14", "D15", "D16", "D17", "D18", "D19", "D20", "D21", "D22", "D23", "D24", "D25", "D26", "D27", "D28", "D29"]
coluna_interpolada_30 = ["D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "D9", "D10", "D11", "D12", "D13", "D14", "D15", "D16", "D17", "D18", "D19", "D20", "D21", "D22", "D23", "D24", "D25", "D26", "D27", "D28", "D29", "D30"]
coluna_interpolada_31 = ["D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "D9", "D10", "D11", "D12", "D13", "D14", "D15", "D16", "D17", "D18", "D19", "D20", "D21", "D22", "D23", "D24", "D25", "D26", "D27", "D28", "D29", "D30", "D31"]



#Interpolation extent
arcpy.env.extent = arcpy.env.workspace + "\\Shapefile\\" + "PB.shp"



#Final list
lista_final = np.array([], dtype = object) 


#Counter that is going to be used to reshape the arrays
contador = 0 


#Loop to go through the time series
for i_ano in ano: #For loop with the years

    for i_mes in mes: #For loop with the months

        #Month Range
        quantidade_dias = monthrange(int(i_ano), int(i_mes))

        #If clauses to define which columns it is goin to interpolate
        if quantidade_dias == (1, 28):
            coluna_interpolada = coluna_interpolada_28
        elif quantidade_dias == (1, 29):
            coluna_interpolada = coluna_interpolada_29
        elif quantidade_dias == (1, 30):
            coluna_interpolada = coluna_interpolada_30
        else:
            coluna_interpolada = coluna_interpolada_31

        #For loop with the days
        for i_dia in coluna_interpolada:

            tabela = i_mes + "_" + i_ano   #Exemplo "2_1994"

            in_Table = arcpy.env.workspace + "\\Dados\\" + tabela + ".csv" #Exemplo "2_1994.csv"
            x_coords = "LONG"
            y_coords = "LAT"
            z_coords = "POINT_Z"
            out_Layer = "espacializacao" + "_" + tabela + "_" + i_dia #nome da camada "lyr" que vai ser criada   
                                                                                        #NOME DO ARQUIVO QUE VAI SER SALVO. Exemplo "espacializacao_2_1994_D2"
            out_Layer_shp = out_Layer + "_shp" #nome da camada "shp" que vai ser criada
            out_Layer_tif = out_Layer + "_tif"
            tamanho_celula = "0,10" #precisar por as aspas, apesar de ser um número
            potencia_idw = "2" #precisa por as aspas, apesar de ser um número
            raio_de_busca = RadiusVariable(12, 12) #Critério para fazer a interpolação, raio variando até 12 quilômetros até conseguir englobar 12 pontos




            # Set the spatial reference
            spRef = arcpy.SpatialReference("WGS 1984")

            #Create event layer
            arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(in_Table, x_coords, y_coords, out_Layer, spRef, "")


            #Exporting event layer as shapefile
            arcpy.FeatureToPoint_management(out_Layer, arcpy.env.workspace + "\\" + "Shapefile\\Exportados\\" + out_Layer_shp + ".shp","")





            #Layer that is going to be deleted "lyr"
            lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "espacializacao",df)



            #Deleting the layer
            for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):
                 for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df): #O parâmetro que não foi passado foi o WildCard, não precisa
                     if lyr.name == out_Layer:
                         arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr) #Removendo a camada da paleta lateral





            #Some variables to define some parameters to the software
            camada_editando = out_Layer_shp
            coluna_criada = "Media"
            tipo_campo = "FLOAT"
            precisao_campo = ""
            precisao_decimais = ""
            comprimento_campo = 50 #Tamanho qualquer suposto
            arcpy.AddField_management(camada_editando, coluna_criada, "LONG", precisao_campo,
                                          precisao_decimais, comprimento_campo, "", "NULLABLE",
                                          "NON_REQUIRED", "")   
            bacias = ["Abiai", "Camaratuba", "Curimatau", "Gramame", "Guaju", "Jacu", "Mamanguape", "Miriri", "Paraiba", "Piranhas", "Trairi"]          




            #Code to interpolate
            arcpy.gp.Idw_sa(out_Layer_shp, i_dia, arcpy.env.workspace + "\\Raster\\" + out_Layer_tif + ".tif", tamanho_celula, potencia_idw, "VARIABLE 12 12", "") 


            #Deleting shapefile
            arcpy.Delete_management(out_Layer_shp, "")  






            #For loop to clip the raster file using the shapefiles
            for mascara in bacias:
                importar_camada = arcpy.env.workspace + "\\Shapefile\\Bacias\\" + mascara + ".shp"  #Importing shapefile to clip
                arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(importar_camada, mascara)  



                #Some variables defining some parameters to using in the clip function
                camada_para_recortar = out_Layer_tif + ".tif"
                camada_resultante = out_Layer + "_recortada"
                nome_do_raster = camada_resultante + "_" + mascara + ".tif" 

                #Function to clip the raster file
                arcpy.Clip_management(camada_para_recortar, "", arcpy.env.workspace  + "\\Raster\\Recortes\\" + camada_resultante + "_" + mascara + ".tif", mascara, "-3,402823e+038", "ClippingGeometry", "NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
                media = arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management (nome_do_raster, "MEAN", "")


                lista_strings = np.array([out_Layer, mascara])
                lista_medias = np.array([media])


                #Name of the file to save the means values
                arquivo_com_as_medias = "medias 01" 


                lista_numpy_temporaria = np.append(lista_strings, lista_medias)
                lista_final = np.concatenate((lista_final, lista_numpy_temporaria))


                #Deleting the raster clipped
                arcpy.Delete_management(nome_do_raster, "") 

                #Counter
                contador = contador + 1 

                print(lista_final)

            #Reshaping the file 
            lista_final = lista_final.reshape(contador,3)       

            print(lista_final)

            #Saving the arrays to a CSV file
            np.savetxt(arcpy.env.workspace  + "\\Dados\\Exportados\\" + arquivo_com_as_medias + ".csv", lista_final, fmt="%10s %10s %10s", delimiter=";", header = "")




            #Deleting the original raster
            arcpy.Delete_management(out_Layer_tif + ".tif", "")
```

Using this code above, the "print(lista_final)" return the following:

> ```
>     >>> print(lista_final)
> [[u'espacializacao_2_1994_D1' u'Abiai' u'111,81740045547']
>  [u'espacializacao_2_1994_D1' u'Camaratuba' u'328,11316935221']
>  [u'espacializacao_2_1994_D1' u'Curimatau' u'273,3234489704']
>  [u'espacializacao_2_1994_D1' u'Gramame' u'223,45285224915']
>  [u'espacializacao_2_1994_D1' u'Guaju' u'393,62130737305']
>  [u'espacializacao_2_1994_D1' u'Jacu' u'312,91506958008']
>  [u'espacializacao_2_1994_D1' u'Mamanguape' u'289,06595204671']
>  [u'espacializacao_2_1994_D1' u'Miriri' u'564,86507415771']
>  [u'espacializacao_2_1994_D1' u'Paraiba' u'330,80016106998']
>  [u'espacializacao_2_1994_D1' u'Piranhas' u'328,95194289264']
>  [u'espacializacao_2_1994_D1' u'Trairi' u'333,04579162598']]
> ```

Another thing that I was thinking was, would this be the best approach to write these outputs in a CSV file? Because I already saw some tutorials using the "CSV module" to write directly to CSV files. However, I already tried it without success.

I am saying this because this code is going to be repeated a lot of times, something like 19.000 times. Because I am using it to interpolate daily rainfall data from a 54 years time series. So, I guess that an array of this size is not a good approach to solve this problem.

Thank you, once more.

### **Edit 2**

I tried what you suggested, but it's still not working. The changes I did were

```
#First attempt 
one = np.array([out_Layer], dtype = object)  
two = np.array([mascara], dtype = object)    
three = np.array([media])      

rarr = np.rec.fromarrays([one, two, three])   

arquivo_com_as_medias = "medias 01" #File with the means values 
csv_directory = arcpy.env.workspace  + "\\Dados\\Exportados\\" + arquivo_com_as_medias + ".csv" 

np.savetxt(csv_directory, rarr, fmt=['%s', '%s', '%f'], delimiter=";")
```

And the error message it's showing now is the following

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 176, in    File
>   "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\records.py", line
>   560, in fromarrays
>       raise ValueError("array-shape mismatch in array %d" % k) ValueError: array-shape mismatch in array 2

The code in the line 176 is

```
rarr = np.rec.fromarrays([one, two, three])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I found was to use the CSV File Reading and Writing library.

I just added the library in the beginning "import csv" and then added the following lines along the code.

First, in the begging, I needed to set the file directory to save the data.

```
#Opening the file to save the data
write_path = main_directory + "\\Dados\\Exportados\\" + "file_name" + ".csv"
file = open(write_path, 'a')
writer = csv.writer(file)
```

The 'a' parameter allows you to append to the end of the file

Then, in the step that I wanted the data to be saved, I added the following line:

```
#Writing to the file
writer.writerow([mes_pelo_nome, ano_pelo_nome, dia_pelo_nome, mascara, media])
```

In the end, I added the following line to close the file:

```
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

At least as far as the error you're getting goes, it's like it says: you're trying to output 3 columns, but are only providing two formats. If you change your `fmt` arg to something like `fmt=['%10s', '%10s', '%10.3f']`, then `np.savetxt` should work.

It's possible you'll run into other errors, such as those relating to the format/contents of the array you're trying to save out. In order to sidestep any such potential errors, you may also want to temporarily add a line to your script like:

```
print(lista_final[:100])
```

right before the `np.savetxt` line. That way, you can make sure that the contents of `lista_final` (at least in the first hundred rows) are actually what you expect them to be before you try to process the array through `savetxt`.

## Edit

When you call `np.concatenate((lista_final, lista_numpy_temporaria))` near the end of your code, you end up forcing all 3 of your columns into a single standard Numpy array. A standard array can only have a single `dtype`, so everything, including the floats in the last column, end up getting converted to strings. You can avoid this by instead joining your columns into a record array (which can have a different dtype for every column). Say that the three column arrays that you're trying to bring together at the end of your script are like this:

```
one = np.array(["u'espacializacao_2_1994_D1'", "u'espacializacao_2_1994_D1'",
       "u'espacializacao_2_1994_D1'", "u'espacializacao_2_1994_D1'",
       "u'espacializacao_2_1994_D1'", "u'espacializacao_2_1994_D1'",
       "u'espacializacao_2_1994_D1'", "u'espacializacao_2_1994_D1'",
       "u'espacializacao_2_1994_D1'", "u'espacializacao_2_1994_D1'",
       "u'espacializacao_2_1994_D1'"], dtype=object)

two = np.array(["u'Abiai'", "u'Camaratuba'", "u'Curimatau'", "u'Gramame'",
       "u'Guaju'", "u'Jacu'", "u'Mamanguape'", "u'Miriri'", "u'Paraiba'",
       "u'Piranhas'", "u'Trairi'"], dtype=object)

three = np.array([111.81740046, 328.11316935, 273.32344897, 223.45285225,
       393.62130737, 312.91506958, 289.06595205, 564.86507416,
       330.80016107, 328.95194289, 333.04579163])
```

You would then join them together in a single record array and then write them out to a `csv` file like so:

```
rarr = np.rec.fromarrays([one, two, three])
np.savetxt('arcgis.csv', rarr, fmt=['%s', '%s', '%f'], delimiter=";")
```

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? What does the output of that `print` statement look like? Once you get that output, post some of it in an edit at the bottom of your question.

Comment: Thanks tel! I tried your solution, and the error related to the error message was solved. However, as you said, a new error message appeared.I will post the message in my question

Comment: I changed the code. However, there is a new error message related to the "np.rec.fromarrays"